# How to make aspect ratio of HTML element 1:1?

Tags: html, css

I have website that uses percentages so it can support many screen resolutions.

Lets say your screenresolution is: 1920x1080 (1080p FULL HD)

I set width of element (let's say 15%), but for some reasons I can't set height (not the problem).

How do I make a div and set it's height based on calculated height in pixels.

In other words, the width becomes 1920*0.15=288px width. How to automatically make the height 288px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `padding` wisely:

```
#someElement {
    width: 15%;
    height: 0;  // this line is important! otwerwise height + padding > width
    padding-bottom: 15%;  
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/PDeBZ/)

This is for 1:1, but you can choose any ratio you want.

Comment: Bless you dude. Answer. Finally. Phew... Dzieki.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use jQuery.  An example:

```
$('#element').height($('#element').innerwidth());
```

Should set the element's height to its innerWidth (which excludes border and margin).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set dimensions for an anchor tag, you must give it `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;`

If you want a any element to achieve 100% height, you must set it to `position:absolute;`.

Comment: I tried `display: block`. `position: absolute` cannot be used since parent object is `position: fixed`, yet thanks for answer.

Comment: No problem, should come in handy in the future I'm sure.